# How can i get lis of all running applications including if application have sub windows open?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Now I can get all processes this way:

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
              var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
              Image ima = icon.ToBitmap();
              ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
              ima = (Image)(new Bitmap(ima, new Size(25, 25)));
              String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
            }
```

The problem is that I don't get all the processes sub windows or tabs like in windows task manager.
In windows task manager for example I see 28 windows of internet explorer but I get only 19.

[image: Windows Task Manager]

You can see that for example the first process is internet explorer and if I will click on it and will expand it I will see inside 28 internet explorer windows(and tabs too).

Or the Windows Explorer there is (7) near it meaning 7 processes of that.

How can I get also all the processes like in windows task manager ?